# Split object into two and renumerate keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to split an object into two parts according to property "amount" (empty string)

```
let myObj = {
"1": {
    "resources": "hotel",
    "amount": "",
    "currency": ""
},
"2": {
    "resources": null,
    "amount": "300.00",
    "currency": "CZK"
},
"3": {
    "resources": null,
    "amount": "500.00",
    "currency": "USD"
},
```

}

to this

```
obj1 = {
"1": {
    "resources": "hotel",
    "amount": "",
    "currency": ""
}}
obj2 = {
"1": {
    "resources": null,
    "amount": "300.00",
    "currency": "CZK"
},
"2": {
    "resources": null,
    "amount": "500.00",
    "currency": "USD"
}}
```

I'm close to solving it but after numerous attempts (push, assign, map) it still does not work. Thx.

Comment: _"I'm close to solving it"_ - would you mind adding those efforts to the question? Try and make them [mcve]s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive your goal like this:

```js
let myObj = {
  "1": {
    "resources": "hotel",
    "amount": "",
    "currency": ""
  },
  "2": {
    "resources": null,
    "amount": "300.00",
    "currency": "CZK"
  },
  "3": {
    "resources": null,
    "amount": "500.00",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
}

const withAmount = {},
  withoutAmount = {};

Object.keys(myObj).forEach(key => {
  const item = myObj[key];
  if (item.amount) {
    withAmount[key] = item;
  } else {
    withoutAmount[key] = item
  }
})

console.log('withAmount:',withAmount)
console.log('withoutAmount:',withoutAmount)
```

Comment: this is my salvation (changed the keys to i++ so both start with 1) THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest and **most readable** solution i have thought of.

```js
const obj = {
    "1": {
        "resources": "hotel",
        "amount": "",
        "currency": ""
    },
    "2": {
        "resources": null,
        "amount": "300.00",
        "currency": "CZK"
    },
    "3": {
        "resources": null,
        "amount": "500.00",
        "currency": "USD"
    }
}

const withAmount = {};
const withoutAmount = {};

for(indexKey in obj) {
  const data = obj[indexKey];
  if(data['amount'] != '') {
    withAmount[indexKey] = data;
  } else {
    withoutAmount[indexKey] = data;
  }
}

console.log({withAmount, withoutAmount});
```

Comment: seems to work - thanks a lot.